# Hibernate Nested Select with Subquery

Tags: hibernate, subquery, hibernate-criteria

I need to make a Hibernate criteria that will call this SQL query

```
SELECT *, (SELECT avg(rating) FROM restaurant_review WHERE restaurant_id = restaurant.id) as "avegrageRating" FROM restaurant;
```

Please help :D

EDIT: 
Here are the Entities:

Restaurant.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurantId")
    public List<RestaurantReview> reviews;
}
```

RestaurantReview.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant_review")
public class RestaurantReview {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer id;

    // This Many to One causes an Unable to build entity manager factory exception
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Integer restaurantId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    public Integer rating;
}
```

I hope this helps.
I need to get a list of ALL restaurants in the restaurant table, with an extra column containing the average rating from the other table.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned your entity here so by assuming your entity i have made the below code please check... Hope it will help you out.

```
Session session=getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Restaurant.class);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("restaurant_review.restaurant_id"),"restaurant_id")
.add(Projections.property("restaurant_review.restaurant_name"),"restaurant_name")
            .add(Projections.alias(Projections.avg("rating"), "rating")).add(Projections.groupProperty("restaurant_review")));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RestaurantPojo.class));  // Create a class having property name mention right sided as above 
    return (List<RestaurantPojo>)criteria.list();
```

Comment: I've edited the question to include much more detailed information. Please check it out

Comment: where is your reference column in RestaurantReview.. eg: @manytoone to  Restaurant

Comment: when i add @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName="id") i get Unable to build entity manager factory exception